# Android make a first time use screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, settings

I want to implement a screen that appears when the user uses the app for the first time, like google does. Is there a special element to use? What would be the best method to check if the user opened the app for the first time?

Comment: You should google for splash screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented this feature in my app in quite a simple way.

I've created a "Tutorial" Activity which shows up when the string (stored in Shared Prefs) "first_user" is equal to false (had problems with booleans...).
It's a simple NoActionBar activity, with fragments for every "page".
I've also used ViewPagerIndicator to put nice little dots at the bottom to indicate progress (see CirclePageIndicator or something of the sort...)

Good luck if you want something more advanced :) !

EDIT : I guess Pablo also shares my opinion. It's a good sign.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look into SharedPreferences. It's pretty simple.

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean firstOpened = preferences.getBoolean("first_opened", true);

    if(firstOpenened) {

         showWelcomeScreen();

         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
         editor.putBoolean("first_opened", false);
         editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single activity as a splash screen for that.

What you should do is to store a flag into Android Shared Preferences, or even into the SQLite Android Database, that changes when you open that Activity.

So, at app startup you can check that flag and depending on its value start the activity or not.

Comment: Thank you, but I think for my app the best way is to just store a flag into Android Shared Preferences :)